Snowflake error : Numeric value '(501.00)' is not recognized
I have a large dataset, about 600 columns. There is a lot of casting happening to get things formatted properly. I am currently getting an error like this:
Numeric value '(501.00)' is not recognized.
However, I can't identify which column has the problem.
Is it possible to identify which column is causing this error (out of 600 columns)???
Thanks!!

Presumably one of the columns that you're trying to cast from a string to a numeric? Does that reduce the number of candidate columns significantly? You could use TRY_TO_NUMERIC (or one of the similar functions) and see which result in a null when the source is not null

Thanks for the reply Nick, I understand that, but that's again lot of manual effort. I wanted to see if there's an easy way to figure out which exact column the issue is. Something like "Numeric value '(501.00)' is not recognized in ID column"

I don't believe there's anyway of you just running your current process and it telling where the issue is. However, writing a SQL script to loop through the columns and capture which one generated an error when you tried to convert it to integer would be relatively trivial

can you provide some more details on when you are getting this error ? while loading the data or selecting from a table ?

just while selecting

Presumably numbers in parentheses are negative. Rather that search through the columns (and repeating the search on different columns next time you get a new data set), you could REGEXP_REPLACE all of the numeric strings as follows:
with t(val) as (
  select * from values
  ('100.47'),
  ('(501.00)')
)
select regexp_replace(val,'[(](.*?)[)]','-\\1') as newval
from t;




NEWVAL




100.47


-501.00




Thank you, but that's just an example I provided, obviously I wanted to see if there's a way to not search through the columns (and repeating the search on different columns next time I get a new data set). As per all the comments, I don't think it's possible to figure out the column directly, but Thank you for your inputs :)
